# Symfony with only FTP access

Tags: symfony1, httpd.conf

I'm currently developing on my local pc, to which I have complete access of course.

However to my production server I have only FTP access.

Now, this step
http://www.symfony-project.org/getting-started/1_4/en/05-Web-Server-Configuration 
On Symfony's installation guide, suggests that I need to edit the httpd.conf 
I was wondering if there's an alternative since I don't have access to it on production.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading [this](http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/InstallingSymfonyOnSharedHostNoSsh). I haven't tried installing Symfony on a shared host, but I see no reason for it not to work.

Generally shared hosts allow you to set configuration parameters in .htaccess files, so you can override httpd.conf without modifying it.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to add a sample .htaccess file that would work according to here http://www.symfony-project.org/cookbook/1_0/en/web_server
So instead of thinking that everyone has access to their webserver, simply adding a file in your project would be a lot more simple.